# OnErrorReturn does not swallow the termination which caused inside flatMap

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Consider this example:

```
   @Test
   public void testOnErrorReturn() {
    final Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> call() throws Exception {
            throw new RuntimeException("Too Bad");
        }
    });
    Observable<String> observable = Observable.intervalRange(0, 5, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<String> apply(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return stringObservable;
                }
            })
            .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    return "That Passed";
                }
            })
            .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("OnComplete first stream.");
                }
            });

    observable.mergeWith(Observable.<String>never())
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("accept() called with: s = [" + s + "]");
                }
            })
            .test().awaitDone(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

output:

```
accept() called with: s = [That Passed]
OnComplete first stream.
```

It only works if set the `onErrorReturn` inside the `flatMap` like this:

```
return stringObservable.onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            return "That Passed early";
                        }
                    });
```

But I lose the error information down in the chain. How can I keep the stream alive and suppress the termination elegantly?

Comment: Which error information you 're losing in the second case? From what I understand the first one terminates on the first try, while the second one emits 5 items with errors and terminates.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to do. One option is to map error and success values inside `flatMap` to something like [`Try`](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_try) type and then handle that in outer `Observable`.

Another option is to delay errors with `.flatMap(function, true)` then the stream will be alive until completion and you will be able to process successful values and will be notified with composite error in the end.